# AMDesignator is set by default although it is not supposed to

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

Our application runs in two environments; sandbox and development. However, both environments run the same operating system. The problem is that when I create a CultureInfo object for Chilean Spanish (es-CL), AMDesignator and PMDesignator objects are populated. However, when I do the same thing in sandbox, there is no value for them. Does anybody know what might cause this problem? I checked [IBM's site](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSS28S_8.1.0/XFDL/i_xfdl_r_formats_es_CL.dita) and it does seem like es-CL does not have AMDesignator.

Comment: This sort of information changes based on Windows Updates etc, and based on different OSes. (There are various differences between Windows 8 and Windows 10, for example.) Is there any particular reason you're looking at an IBM site for this information?

Comment: Someone tweaked culture settings on your "sandbox" machine? If it is really sandbox - consider just re-installing OS there ...

Comment: There is no particular reason, I was just trying to find out actual fomatting for that culture. I also checked this PDF file from Microsoft  http://download.microsoft.com/download/c/8/0/c80371fa-bc89-46a7-883d-071d59f0c24c/spa-esp-StyleGuide.pdf. This shows the same settings as IBM.

Comment: Also consider that version updates and hotfixes to the .NET Framework often include localization updates, such as [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd997383.aspx).